# How do I set my loader to timeout without interfering with other requests?

Tags: jquery, onsen-ui

I have a loader like this:

```
<ons-modal var="loader">
  <img src="loader_round" class="loader-logo" />
</ons-modal>
```

Which is called with

`loader.show();`

and I am using it within other functions like:

```
function onRequestSuccess()
{   
    loader.show();
}
```

Problem is, I want the loader to disappear after 5 seconds no matter what, but I don't want it to interfere with the `function onRequestSuccess`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
function onRequestSuccess() {

   $(".loader-logo").show();
   setTimeout(function () {

   $('.loader-logo').hide();
}, 10000);
}
```